# Looking for an element in a non-Jagged 2D Byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq, multidimensional-array

I have created a **2D Byte Array** with *3 rows and columns* (order 3*3 Matrix) and ***it's not a Jagged Array***.

```
var arr = new byte[3,3];
```

But now I have to know if a specific element exists in the array or not. I have tried many methods but they work with a 1D array or a Jagged array. 
*Can you think of a way to search the complete 2D array for a specific element?*

Comment: have you tried this `for(int i = 0; i< 3;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < 3; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i,j] == x)
        {
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Every element in an array of `byte` (or any other value type) *exists*.  If you want to look at a specific element (say, `i,j`) then you'd just look at `arr[i,j]`.  What are you asking?  Do you want to find the indexes of the first element whose value is, for example `0xab`?

Comment: Mus t be a dupe somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods:

- Traditional nested foreach, one for every dimension
- Simple foreach, arrays are enumerable
- Linq

#### Nested foreach

```
byte valueToFind = ...
byte[,] values = new byte[3,3];
var xLength = items.GetLength(0);
var yLength = items.GetLength(1);

bool valueFound = false;
int x = 0;
while (!valueFound && x < xLength)
{
for (int x=0; x<xLength; ++x)
{
    int y = 0;
    while (!valueFound && y < yLength)
    {
        valueFound = values[x, y] == valueToFind;
        ++y;
    }
    ++x;
}
return valueFound;
```

Note that the indexes are one more than the index of the actual found element:

```
if (valueFount)
{
    xIndex = --x;
    yIndex = --y;
}
```

#### Simple foreach

Every array is enumerable. If you are not interested in the index of the element:

```
foreach (var value in values)
{
    valueFound = value == valueToFind;
    if (valueFound) break;
}
```

#### LINQ

The shortest method: use LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
bool valueFound = values.Any(value => value == valueToFind)
```

What this does: take the enumerable sequence of values and start enumerating at the first value. Check every value whether it is equal to valueToFind. Stop as soon as you've found one. The return value is true if a value has been found.